# How to connect to git remote via ssh on Media Temple Centos?

Tags: git, ssh, centos7, mediatemple

I've created a new user on my Centos 7, added a .ssh folder with my public key in authorized_keys. I am able to successfully connect via ssh to the server with that user with

```
ssh <username>@<ipaddress>
```

I have also created a bare git repo on the server at:

```
/var/repo/<reponame>.git
```

and added a remote on my local machine using:

```
git remote add origin <username>@<ipaddress>:/var/repo/<reponame>.git
```

When I run:

```
git remote show origin
```

or

```
git push origin master
```

It hangs, then gives the response:

```
ssh: connect to host <ipaddress> port 22: Operation timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I'm not sure why I can successfully connect via SSH, but this command fails. Any help you could provide would be absolutely amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Check first if your successfull ssh connection comes with outputs from the remote user `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`.

Ideally, it should be silent.

Check also if `git` is available (in the default system PATH) when you open an interactive SSH session.